# Bashrc not loading when running manpager

Tags: bash, vim, man, pager, ansi

I have found issues with using the `MANPAGER` variable in bash in order to set vim to be my manpager.

Initially I set my manpager using the method shown in `:help manpager` by doing:

```
export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"
man fzf
```

This opens up the man page but does not display ANSI colours but displays the colour codes, however if I simply run

```
man fzf | vim -M +MANPAGER -
```

The man page displays correctly with ANSI colouring enabled. I tried to use the AnsiEsc·vim plugin to display the colours by setting the `MANPAGER` variable as follows

```
export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -c 'AnsiEsc' -"
```

However with this method, the ANSI codes are gone but the text does not become coloured. I have discovered that for some reason this is due to the fact that when you set the `MANPAGER` variable and then display the man page, your `bashrc` settings do not get loaded. I checked this because I have an alias in my `bashrc` which maps the command `v` to `vim`, therefore when I run:

```
man fzf | v -M +MANPAGER -
```

I get the same (valid) result as running the same command with `vim`. However when I run:

```
export MANPAGER="v -M +MANPAGER -"
man fzf
```

I get the error:

```
man: can't execute v: No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 255: sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{ N; /^[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/D; }' | LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual p
age fzf(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page fzf(1) ?ltline
 %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=fzf(1) v -M +MANPAGER -
```

Is my assumption that `bashrc` is not loaded when running `man` correct and if so is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: "I have discovered that for some reason this is due to the fact that [...] your bashrc settings do not get loaded. " How did you discover that *this* is the reason? `man` doesn't run a shell to start `$MANPAGER`, so there's nothing to load your bashrc.

Comment: Yes I agree but I assumed it based on my testing. I am basically asking why my alias does not work in the last scenario and I believe that the same reason is why the other issues exist, although I am not sure

Comment: I gave you the  reason why your alias didn't work in my comment. Unless your alias is modifying Vim settings in some way, it's unrelated to the manpager problem.

Comment: but surely it runs in the same shell in which I run `man fzf` therefore it should be able to use the alias which is in the bash shell it is called from?

Comment: "`man` doesn't run a shell to start `$MANPAGER`, so there's nothing to load your bashrc."